# Boolean algebra/ring: Compute product of sum of combinations of variables

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean-ring

Let's say I have a set of variables $a_1, ... ,a_n \in \{0, 1\}$ and a boolean algebra where multiplication is $\land$ and sum is $\oplus$ (exclusive or). This is like in bit operations in computers.

Let's define $c_n(k)$ as the sum of the products of all the ${n \choose k}$ $k$-combinations of the $n$ variables. For example:

$$c_3(1) = a_1 \oplus a_2 \oplus a_3$$
$$c_3(2) = a_1a_2 \oplus a_1a_3 \oplus a_2a_3 = a_1 \land a_2 \oplus a_1 \land a_3 \oplus a_2 \land a_3$$

I would like to be able to get a general formula for all $c_n(k)c_n(j)$ products. For example I can compute:

$$c_3(2)c_3(1) = c_3(3)$$
$$c_4(1)c_4(4) = 0$$

and obviously:

$$c_n(k)c_n(k) = c_n(k)$$

The formula could be restricted to some $n$ values only, but arbitrarily large, for example only to $n$ even or odd, or only e.g. $n = 2^m$, or $n = 2^{2m}$, or something else, if it is simpler.

Where to start? Should I use induction? Is there already some work done on this?
Thank you for any idea!

After making a calculator program I was able to compute also the following:

$\small{c_3(1)c_3(3) = c_3(3)}$,
$\small{c_3(2)c_3(3) = c_3(3)}$

$\small{c_4(1)c_4(2) = c_4(3)}$,
$\small{c_4(1)c_4(3) = c_4(3)}$,
$\small{c_4(1)c_4(4) = 0}$,
$\small{c_4(2)c_4(3) = c_4(3)}$,
$\small{c_4(2)c_4(4) = 0}$,
$\small{c_4(3)c_4(4) = 0}$

$\small{c_5(1)c_5(2) = c_5(3)}$,
$\small{c_5(1)c_5(3) = c_5(3)}$,
$\small{c_5(1)c_5(4) = c_5(5)}$,
$\small{c_5(1)c_5(5) = c_5(5)}$,
$\small{c_5(2)c_5(3) = c_5(3)}$,
$\small{c_5(2)c_5(4) = 0}$,
$\small{c_5(2)c_5(5) = 0}$,
$\small{c_5(3)c_5(4) = 0}$,
$\small{c_5(3)c_5(5) = 0}$,
$\small{c_5(4)c_5(5) = c_5(5)}$

$\small{c_6(1)c_6(2) = c_6(3)}$,
$\small{c_6(1)c_6(3) = c_6(3) }$,
$\small{c_6(1)c_6(4) = c_6(5)}$,
$\small{c_6(1)c_6(5) = c_6(5)}$,
$\small{c_6(1)c_6(6) = 0}$,
$\small{c_6(2)c_6(3) = c_6(3)}$,
$\small{c_6(2)c_6(4) = c_6(6)}$,
$\small{c_6(2)c_6(5) = 0}$,
$\small{c_6(2)c_6(6) = c_6(6)}$,
$\small{c_6(3)c_6(4) = 0}$,
$\small{c_6(3)c_6(5) = 0}$,
$\small{c_6(3)c_6(6) = 0}$,
$\small{c_6(4)c_6(5) = c_6(5)}$,
$\small{c_6(4)c_6(6) = c_6(6)}$,
$\small{c_6(5)c_6(6) = 0}$

$\small{c_7(1)c_7(2) = c_7(3)}$,
$\small{c_7(1)c_7(3) = c_7(3)}$,
$\small{c_7(1)c_7(4) = c_7(5)}$,
$\small{c_7(1)c_7(5) = c_7(5)}$,
$\small{c_7(1)c_7(6) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(1)c_7(7) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(2)c_7(3) = c_7(3)}$,
$\small{c_7(2)c_7(4) = c_7(6)}$,
$\small{c_7(2)c_7(5) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(2)c_7(6) = c_7(6)}$,
$\small{c_7(2)c_7(7) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(3)c_7(4) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(3)c_7(5) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(3)c_7(6) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(3)c_7(7) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(4)c_7(5) = c_7(5)}$,
$\small{c_7(4)c_7(6) = c_7(6)}$,
$\small{c_7(4)c_7(7) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(5)c_7(6) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(5)c_7(7) = c_7(7)}$,
$\small{c_7(6)c_7(7) = c_7(7)}$

$\small{c_8(1)c_8(2) = c_8(3)}$,
$\small{c_8(1)c_8(3) = c_8(3)}$,
$\small{c_8(1)c_8(4) = c_8(5)}$,
$\small{c_8(1)c_8(5) = c_8(5)}$,
$\small{c_8(1)c_8(6) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(1)c_8(7) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(1)c_8(8) = 0}$,
$\small{c_8(2)c_8(3) = c_8(3)}$,
$\small{c_8(2)c_8(4) = c_8(6)}$,
$\small{c_8(2)c_8(5) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(2)c_8(6) = c_8(6)}$,
$\small{c_8(2)c_8(7) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(2)c_8(8) = 0}$,
$\small{c_8(3)c_8(4) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(3)c_8(5) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(3)c_8(6) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(3)c_8(7) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(3)c_8(8) = 0}$,
$\small{c_8(4)c_8(5) = c_8(5)}$,
$\small{c_8(4)c_8(6) = c_8(6)}$,
$\small{c_8(4)c_8(7) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(4)c_8(8) = 0}$,
$\small{c_8(5)c_8(6) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(5)c_8(7) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(5)c_8(8) = 0}$,
$\small{c_8(6)c_8(7) = c_8(7)}$,
$\small{c_8(6)c_8(8) = 0}$,
$\small{c_8(7)c_8(8) = 0}$

Based on these experimental results I suspect that the formula might be something like this:

$$c_n(k)c_n(j) =
\begin{cases}
c_n(k \lor j),  & \text{if $k < n$ and $j < n$} \\[2ex]
0, & \text{if $k = n$ and ${n \choose j}$ is even or $j = n$ and ${n \choose k}$ is even} \\[2ex]
c_n(n), & \text{if $k = n$ and ${n \choose j}$ is odd or $j = n$ and ${n \choose k}$ is odd}
\end{cases}$$

where $k \lor j$ is the number obtained as the bitwise OR of the binary representations of $k$ and $j$.

Comment: Your second product identity can be generalized to $c_n(k)c_n(n)=0$ if $\binom{n}k$ is even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) are related to your function by $$e_k(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)\equiv c_n(k)\pmod{2}$$
where multiplication mod $2$ is $\wedge$ and addition mod $2$ is $\oplus$.  For completeness, let $c_n(0):=1$.

[Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) is that a polynomial with roots $a_1,\dots,a_n$ with multiplicity is given by $f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^ie_i(a_1,\dots,a_n)x^{n-i}$.  If we think of a particular assignment of $0$'s and $1$'s to $a_1,\dots,a_n$, then we can also write $f(x)=x^a(x-1)^b$, where $a,b$ are the numbers of $0$'s and $1$'s (with $a+b=n$).  Expanded, this is $f(x)=\sum_{j=0}^b\binom{b}{j}x^{a+b-j}(-1)^j$.  Modulo $2$, we get
$$\sum_{i=0}^ne_i(a_1,\dots,a_n)x^{n-i}\equiv\sum_{j=0}^b\binom{b}{j}x^{n-j}\pmod{2}.$$
Matching up coefficients, $e_k(a_1,\dots,a_n)\equiv\binom{b}{k}\pmod{2}$.  That is, $c_n(k)\equiv\binom{b}{k}\pmod{2}$ when $b$ is the number of variables set to $1$.  (By the way, construct Pascal's triangle modulo $2$ if you haven't already.  Do it out far enough until you recognize the shape.)

[Lucas's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27s_theorem) can be used to understand these binomial coefficients.  Write $b=\sum_{i=0}^m b_i2^i$ and $k=\sum_{i=0}^m k_i2^i$, with $b_0,\dots,b_m,k_0,\dots,k_m\in\{0,1\}$. That is, as base-2 representations.  Then $\binom{b}{k}\equiv\prod_{i=0}^m\binom{b_i}{k_i}\pmod{2}$, where recall $\binom{0}{1}=0$.  Logically, with $p,q\in\{0,1\}$, $\binom{p}{q}$ is $q\to p$ ($q$ implies $p$) since if $q=0$ the coefficient is $1$, and if $q=1$, then the coefficient is $p$.

Let $j$ be another number and let $j_0,\dots,j_m$ be similar.  Then,
$$c_n(k)c_n(j)\equiv\binom{b}{k}\binom{b}{j}\equiv \prod_{i=0}^m\binom{b_i}{k_i}\binom{b_i}{j_i}$$
Recall that $(k_i\to b_i)\wedge(j_i\to b_i)$ is logically $(k_i\vee j_i)\to b_i$, so we have
$$c_n(k)c_n(j)\equiv\prod_{i=0}^m\binom{b_i}{k_i\vee j_i}\equiv\binom{b}{k\vee j}$$
using your bitwise-OR notation.

This holds for all $b$. Thus, if $k\vee j\leq n$, $c_n(k)c_n(j)=c_n(k\vee j)$.  Otherwise, if $k\vee j > n$, $c_n(k)c_n(j)=0$.

If you define $c_n(m)=0$ when $m>n$, then it is just
$$c_n(k)c_n(j)=c_n(k\vee j).$$

---

There might be other interesting identities one can get from [Newton's identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities), but I couldn't find any.  They involve $p_k(a_1,\dots,a_n)=a_1^k+\dots+a_n^k$, which is just $e_1(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ when mod $2$ and $k\geq 1$.  So, the identity
$$ke_k(a_1,\dots,a_n)=\sum_{i=1}^k(-1)^{i-1}e_{k-i}(a_1,\dots,a_n)p_i(a_1,\dots,a_n)$$
when reduced mod $2$ is
$$ke_k(a_1,\dots,a_n)\equiv\sum_{i=1}^ke_{k-i}(a_1,\dots,a_n)e_1(a_1,\dots,a_n)\pmod{2}$$
or
$$kc_n(k)\equiv c_n(1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}c_n(j)\pmod{2}.$$

For example, if $k=3$, we get $c_n(3)=c_n(1)(1+c_n(1)+c_n(2))$.

But, distributing the right hand side we get $c_n(1)+c_n(1)+c_n(1)c_n(2)=c_n(3)$, which is nothing new.

Comment: Thank you! I could never have done it myself. By the way every natural number $m \le n = 2^p$ can be expressed as: $$m = \sum_{i=1}^{p}c_n(2^i)2^i$$ provided that $a_1=\ldots=a_m=1$ and $a_{m+1}=\ldots=a_n=0$. That expression could be used to compute a certain $f(m)$ (for example the Collatz function) over an entire interval $1 \le m \le n$.

Comment: I guess that's because $c_n(2^i)=\binom{m}{2^i}\pmod{2}$ (with your assignment of $1$'s and $0$'s), which according to Lucas's theorem is the $i$th bit of $m$.  I'm not seeing how it applies to the Collatz function, but it could be interesting if it does.

Comment: Because for $m=\sum_{i=0}^{p}m_i2^i$ the Collatz function is: $f(m)=\sum_{i=1}^{p}m_i2^{i-1}+\sum_{i=1}^{p}m_0m_i2^i+m_02$ so it is possible to compute binary coefficients at each step as some $\sum_{i}c_n(k_i)$. Probably not of much use though, since a numeric verification is much faster.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\peq{\mathrel{\phantom{=}}{}}$**Step 1:** Preliminary analysis.

Note that in this system, $a + a = 0$ and $a^2 = a$ for any $a$. For any $1 \leqslant k, l \leqslant n$, suppose$$
c_n(k) c_n(l) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\min(k + l, n)} b_m c_n(m),
$$
where $b_1, \cdots, b_{\min(k + l, n)} \in \{0, 1\}$. Note that for any $A, B \subseteq \{1, \cdots, n\}$, there is$$
\left( \prod_{i \in A} a_i \right)\left( \prod_{j \in B} a_j \right) = \prod_{i \in A \cup B} a_i,
$$
and $|A| = k,\ |B| = l \Rightarrow |A \cup B| \geqslant \max(k, l)$, thus $b_m = 0$ for $1 \leqslant m < \max(k, l)$. For $\max(k, l) \leqslant m \leqslant \min(n, k + l)$, in order to determine $b_m$, it suffices to find the number of set pairs $(A, B)$ that satisfy the following requirements:

1. $A, B \subseteq \{1, \cdots, n\}$,

   $|A| = k$, $|B| = l$, $A \cup B = \{1, \cdots, m\}$.

First, there are $C(m, k)$ ways to select $A$. After fixing $A$, note that $\{1, \cdots, m\} \setminus A \subseteq B$, thus there are $C(k, l - (m - k))$ ways to select $B$. Therefore,$$
b_m \equiv C(m, k) C(k, l - (m - k)) \equiv \frac{m!}{(m - k)!\, (m - l)!\, (k + l - m)!} \pmod{2}.
$$

**Step 2:** For any $k, l \geqslant 1$, there exists a unique $m = f(k, l)$ such that $\max(k, l) \leqslant m \leqslant k + l$ and $\dfrac{m!}{(m - k)!\, (m - l)!\, (k + l - m)!}$ is odd.

*Proof:* Two lemmas first.

**Lemma 1:** For any $a, b, c \ge 0$,$$
\frac{(a + b + c)!}{a!\, b!\, c!} \text{ is odd} \Longleftrightarrow \forall j \geqslant 1:\ \left\{ \frac{a}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{b}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{c}{2^j} \right\} < 1,
$$
where $\{x\} = x - [x]$ is the fractional part of $x$.

*Proof:* Note that for any $n \geqslant 0$, [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula)
$$
ν_2(n) = \sum_{j = 1}^∞ \left[ \frac{n}{2^j} \right]
$$
gives the exponent of the largest power of $2$ that divides $n!$. Since $a!\, b!\, c! \mid (a + b + c)!$, then$$
\frac{(a + b + c)!}{a!\, b!\, c!} \text{ is odd} \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{j = 1}^∞ \left[ \frac{a + b + c}{2^j} \right] = \sum_{j = 1}^∞ \left( \left[ \frac{a}{2^j} \right] + \left[ \frac{b}{2^j} \right] + \left[ \frac{c}{2^j} \right] \right).
$$
Because\begin{align*}
&\peq \sum_{j = 1}^∞ \left( \left[ \frac{a + b + c}{2^j} \right] - \left( \left[ \frac{a}{2^j} \right] + \left[ \frac{b}{2^j} \right] + \left[ \frac{c}{2^j} \right] \right) \right)\\
&= \sum_{j = 1}^∞ \left[ \frac{a + b + c}{2^j} - \left( \left[ \frac{a}{2^j} \right] + \left[ \frac{b}{2^j} \right] + \left[ \frac{c}{2^j} \right] \right) \right]\\
&= \sum_{j = 1}^∞ \left[ \left\{ \frac{a}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{b}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{c}{2^j} \right\} \right],
\end{align*}
then\begin{align*}
&\mathrel{\phantom{\longleftrightarrow}}{} \sum_{j = 1}^∞ \left[ \frac{a + b + c}{2^j} \right] = \sum_{j = 1}^∞ \left( \left[ \frac{a}{2^j} \right] + \left[ \frac{b}{2^j} \right] + \left[ \frac{c}{2^j} \right] \right)\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \forall j \geqslant 1:\ \left[ \left\{ \frac{a}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{b}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{c}{2^j} \right\} \right] = 0\\
&\Longleftrightarrow \forall j \geqslant 1:\ \left\{ \frac{a}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{b}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{c}{2^j} \right\} < 1.
\end{align*}

**Lemma 2:** For any $m, n \in \mathbb{N}_+$, there exists $a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\left\{ \dfrac{m}{n} \right\} = \dfrac{a}{n}$. (Proof omitted.)

Now back to step 2. It will be proved by induction on $r \geqslant 0$ that the proposition holds for $1 \leqslant k, l \leqslant 2^r$.

For $r = 0$, if $k = l = 1$, then $1 \leqslant m \leqslant 2$ and the only $m$ that satisfies the requirements is $m = 1$. Now assume that the proposition holds for $1 \leqslant k, l \leqslant 2^r$. For $1 \leqslant k, l \leqslant 2^{r + 1}$, there are three cases.

*Case 1:* Both $k$ and $l$ are even. Suppose $k = 2k_0$ and $l = 2l_0$, then $k_0, l_0 \geqslant 1$. On the one hand, suppose $m_0 = f(k_0, l_0)$ and $m = 2m_0$, then$$
\left\{ \frac{2m_0 - 2k_0}{2} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_0 - 2l_0}{2} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2k_0 + 2l_0 - 2m_0}{2} \right\} = 0 < 1.
$$
For $j \geqslant 2$, by lemma 1 and induction hypothesis,\begin{align*}
&\peq \left\{ \frac{2m_0 - 2k_0}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_0 - 2l_0}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2k_0 + 2l_0 - 2m_0}{2^j} \right\}\\
&= \left\{ \frac{m_0 - k_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{m_0 - l_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} < 1.
\end{align*}
Thus by lemma 1, $m = 2m_0$ satisfies the requirements. On the other hand, for any $m$ that satisfies the requirements, if $m$ is odd, then$$
\left\{ \frac{m - 2k_0}{2} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{m - 2l_0}{2} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2k_0 + 2l_0 - m}{2} \right\} = \frac{3}{2} > 1,
$$
a contradiction by lemma 1. Suppose $m = 2m_1$, then $\max(k_0, l_0) \leqslant m_1 \leqslant k_0 + l_0$. For any $j \geqslant 1$, by lemma 1,\begin{align*}
&\peq \left\{ \frac{m_1 - k_0}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{m_1 - l_0}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_1}{2^j} \right\}\\
&= \left\{ \frac{2m_1 - 2k_0}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_1 - 2l_0}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2k_0 + 2l_0 - 2m_1}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} < 1,
\end{align*}
which by lemma 1 and induction hypothesis implies $m_1 = f(k_0, l_0)$.

*Case 2:* One of $k$ and $l$ is odd and the other is even. Without loss of generality, suppose $k = 2k_0 + 1$ and $l = 2l_0$, then $l_0 \geqslant 1$. If $k_0 = 0$, then $2l_0 \leqslant m \leqslant 2l_0 + 1$ and $m = 2l_0 + 1$ is the only $m$ that satisfies the requirements.

Now assume that $k_0 \geqslant 1$. On the one hand, suppose $m_0 = f(k_0, l_0)$ and $m = 2m_0 + 1$, then$$
\left\{ \frac{2m_0 + 1 - 2k_0 - 1}{2} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_0 + 1 - 2l_0}{2} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2k_0 + 1 + 2l_0 - 2m_0 - 1}{2} \right\} = \frac{1}{2} < 1.
$$
For $j \geqslant 2$, note that$$
2m_0 + 1 - 2l_0 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{2^j} \Longrightarrow \left\{ \frac{2m_0 + 1 - 2l_0}{2^j} \right\} \geqslant \frac{1}{2^j},
$$
thus\begin{align*}
&\peq \left\{ \frac{2m_0 + 1 - 2k_0 - 1}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_0 + 1 - 2l_0}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2k_0 + 1 + 2l_0 - 2m_0 - 1}{2^j} \right\}\\
&= \left\{ \frac{m_0 - k_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_0 - 2l_0}{2^j} \right\} + \frac{1}{2^j} + \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\}\\
&= \left\{ \frac{m_0 - k_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{m_0 - l_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \frac{1}{2^j}.
\end{align*}
By lemma 1 and induction hypothesis,$$
\left\{ \frac{m_0 - k_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{m_0 - l_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} < 1,
$$
and lemma 2 implies$$
\left\{ \frac{m_0 - k_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{m_0 - l_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} \leqslant 1 - \frac{1}{2^{j - 1}},
$$
then$$
\left\{ \frac{m_0 - k_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{m_0 - l_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\}+ \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_0}{2^{j - 1}} \right\} + \frac{1}{2^j} \leqslant 1 - \frac{1}{2^{j - 1}} + \frac{1}{2^j} < 1.
$$
Thus by lemma 1, $m = 2m_0 + 1$ satisfies the requirements. On the other hand, for any $m$ that satisfies the requirements, if $m$ is even, then$$
\left\{ \frac{m - 2k_0 - 1}{2} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{m - 2l_0}{2} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2k_0 + 1 + 2l_0 - m}{2} \right\} = 1,
$$
a contradiction by lemma 1. Suppose $m = 2m_1 + 1$, then $\max(k_0, l_0) \leqslant m_1 \leqslant k_0 + l_0$ (note that $2m_1 + 1 \geqslant 2l_0 \Rightarrow m_1 \geqslant l_0$). For any $j \geqslant 1$, by lemma 1,$$
\left\{ \frac{2m_1 + 1 - 2k_0 - 1}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_1 + 1 - 2l_0}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2k_0 + 1 + 2l_0 - 2m_1 - 1}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} < 1.
$$
Note that$$
2m_1 + 1 - 2l_0 \not\equiv 0 \pmod{2^{j + 1}} \Longrightarrow \left\{ \frac{2m_1 + 1 - 2l_0}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} \geqslant \frac{1}{2^{j + 1}},
$$
thus\begin{align*}
&\peq \left\{ \frac{m_1 - k_0}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{m_1 - l_0}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_1}{2^j} \right\}\\
&= \left\{ \frac{m_1 - k_0}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_1 + 1 - 2l_0}{2^{j + 1}} - \frac{1}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_1}{2^j} \right\}\\
&= \left\{ \frac{m_1 - k_0}{2^j} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_1 + 1 - 2l_0}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} - \frac{1}{2^{j + 1}} + \left\{ \frac{k_0 + l_0 - m_1}{2^j} \right\}\\
&= \left\{ \frac{2m_1 + 1 - 2k_0 - 1}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2m_1 + 1 - 2l_0}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} + \left\{ \frac{2k_0 + 1 + 2l_0 - 2m_1 - 1}{2^{j + 1}} \right\} - \frac{1}{2^{j + 1}}\\
&< 1 - \frac{1}{2^{j + 1}} < 1,
\end{align*}
which by lemma 1 and induction hypothesis implies $m_1 = f(k_0, l_0)$.

*Case 3:* Both $k$ and $l$ are odd. Suppose $k = 2k_0 + 1$, $l = 2l_0 + 1$. If at least one of $k_0$ and $l_0$ is $0$, without loss of generality, assume that $k_0 = 0$, then $2l_0 + 1 \leqslant m \leqslant 2l_0 + 2$ and $m = 2l_0 + 1$ is the only $m$ that satisfies the requirements.

Now suppose $k_0, l_0 \geqslant 1$ and take $m_0 = f(k_0, l_0)$. By deduction analogous to case 2, $m = 2m_0 + 1$ is the only $m$ that satisfies the requirements.

Therefore, the proposition holds for $1 \leqslant k, l \leqslant 2^{r + 1}$. End of induction.

**Step 3:** For any $k, l \geqslant 1$, there is $f(k, l) = k \lor l$, where $\lor$ represents bitwise OR (e.g. $5 \lor 13 = (0101)_2 \lor (1101)_2 = (1101)_2 = 13$), and for any $n \geqslant 1$,$$
c_n(k) c_n(l) = \begin{cases}
c_n(k \lor l); & k \lor l \leqslant n\\
0; & k \lor l > n
\end{cases}.
$$

*Proof:* From the proof of step 2, $f$ satisfies the following recurrence relations for $k, l \geqslant 2$:$$
f(k, l) = \begin{cases}
2 f\left( \frac{k}{2}, \frac{l}{2} \right); & 2 \mid k,\ 2 \mid l\\
2 f\left( \left[ \frac{k}{2} \right], \left[ \frac{l}{2} \right] \right) + 1; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases},
$$
and $f(k, 1) = f(1, k) = 2 \left[ \dfrac{k}{2} \right] + 1$ for $k \geqslant 1$. If further define $f(k, 0) = f(0, k) = k$ for $k \geqslant 0$, then$$
f(k, l) = \begin{cases}
2 f\left( \frac{k}{2}, \frac{l}{2} \right); & 2 \mid k,\ 2 \mid l\\
2 f\left( \left[ \frac{k}{2} \right], \left[ \frac{l}{2} \right] \right) + 1; & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
hold for $k, l \geqslant 1$. Now it is easy to prove by induction on $k \geqslant 0$ that $f(k, l) = k \lor l\ (\forall l \geqslant 0)$.

Finally, for any $n \geqslant 1$ and $1 \leqslant k, l \leqslant n$, if $k \lor l \leqslant n$, then step 1 and step 2 imply $b_{k \lor l} = 1$, $b_m = 0\ (m ≠ k \lor l)$ and $c_n(k) c_n(l) = c_n(k \lor l)$. Otherwise, step 1 and step 2 imply $b_m = 0$ for all $m$ and $c_n(k) c_n(l) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, although I preferred to reward the other answer because it looks simpler to me. See the comment below regarding the binary representation with $c_n(2^i)$ coefficients.